# Angular 6 получение информацию об ошибке и сделать запрос

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

В документации утверждают, что поймать ошибку можно `pipe`, `tap` или `catchError`, если правильно понял. Что мне сделать когда я получаю ошибку **401**, Мне нужно поймать ошибку и  сделать `post` запрос для `refreh_token` и повторно сделать тот же вопрос на котором получил ошибку **401**, вот пример кода, но оно не работает.

**service.ts**

```
getData(dataUrl) {
        this.isloading.next({type: 'get', isLoading: true, reqCount: ++this.reqCount});
        const url = dataUrl;
        const header = new HttpHeaders()
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token'))
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        const request = this.http.get(url, {
            headers: header,
            observe: 'response'
        }).finally(() => {
            this.isloading.next({type: 'get', isLoading: false, reqCount: --this.reqCount});
        }).pipe(
            tap((res) => {
                if (res.headers.get('warning')[0] === '1') {
                    this.openModal();
                } else if (res.headers.get('warning')[0] === '2') {
                    this.router.navigateByUrl('/profile');
                }
            }),
            map((res) => {
                return res.body;
            }),
            catchError((err: any) => {
                console.log(err);
                if (err.status === 401) {
                    let data = {
                        'refresh_token': localStorage.getItem('refresh_token'),


             'id': localStorage.getItem('user_id')
                };
                // refresh_token запрос
                this.createData(environment.refresh, data).subscribe((res) => {
                    localStorage.setItem('access_token', res['access_token']);
                    localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res['refresh_token']);
                    this.alertService.success(this.labels['token_update']);
                    console.log(err.url);
                    // повтор на тот же запрос в котором поличл ошибку 401 код
                    const url = err.url;
                    const header = new HttpHeaders()
                        .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token'))
                        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                    const request = this.http.get(url, {
                        headers: header,
                        observe: 'response'
                    }).finally(() => {
                        this.isloading.next({type: 'get', isLoading: false, reqCount: --this.reqCount});
                    });
                    return request;
                });
            }
            throw err;
        })
    );
    return request;

}
```

Comment: я не вижу такого утверждения в документации, `tap - Transparently perform actions or side-effects, such as logging`. Откуда у `Observable` метод `finally`? Он был только в `rxjs 4`, а так как вы используете `pipe`, у вас однозначно `rxjs >= 5.5`

Comment: у меня `"rxjs": "6.1.0",` это просто для `Loading`

Comment: рефреш токена нужно делать с помощью перехватчиков и ни в коем случае в компонентах или сервисах, они для этого предназначены, потому что выходит так, что вы логику рефреша будете везде писать

Comment: Наверно тебе просто нужно добавить второй аргумент в `catchError`.

Comment: @epsilon, и что произойдет и как это поможет рефрешнуть токен !?

Answer (score 0):

Судя из вашего описания Вам необходима не обработка ошибок.
Для рефреша токена используются интерцепторы и уже в них можно описать соответствующую логику.

Вот [тут](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8) статья, которая содержит пример обработки оеспонса со статусом 401

Официальное описание интерцепторов [тут](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor).

Comment: это больше похоже на комментарий, нежели на полноценный ответ, который решает проблему